# Define plot color by density of overlap with other plots in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm looking to plot multiple GPS tracks from lat, long points. I build each plot individually and then show them all on the same final figure. I am wondering if I can use the overlap of the individual plots to define their color at that point. Essentially, I want to create a heatmap based in different colors instead of just alpha, so I can still see every track.

Currently, each plot is simply put together with:

```
plt.plot(lon, lat, color = 'deepskyblue', lw = 0.2, alpha = 0.8)
```

Comment: This involves several steps. (1) Find a good measure of "overlap". This may be the hardest part - or it may be easy, depending on how dense your points are. (2) Calculate the density. (3) Colorize the line segments according to calculated density. Advance stepwise, don't ask or care about (3) as long as you haven't solved (1).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I'm definitely stuck on (1) at the moment. Just the density of the points doesn't necessarily give me what I want, and it's the actual overlap of the segments that I want to measure. And I haven't quite figured out how to work backward there. If I could use the cumulative alpha at any point in my overlaid plot to determine the color, this might be a decent method. ie: every line is a = 0.1, an area of overlap between two has a = 0.2 and is, therefore, a "hotter" color.

Comment: I might be able to "bootstrap" it and plot it initially with just a single color and the alpha setting and then reanalyze the resulting plot as an image and assign color based on the previous pixel "intensity". That doesn't sound like the most coherent way to go about this though.

Comment: A line does not have any extent. Two lines cross at exactly one point in space. So apparently you try to define some density measure based on the zoom level, the more you zoom in, the less overlap. I wonder how useful that concept is and what kind of information it conveys. Did you consider interpolating the line segments such as to define a spacial (instead of visual) density?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I'm attempting to make a heatmap that shows where I've traveled. To do this effectively, I'd need to give the lines a weight beyond a single point to capture realistic overlap.

Comment: Interpolating will give you more points which you can then use to do statistics.